# Smooth transition between positions for ball program java

Tags: java, positioning

Currently I am working on a very simple java ball program. The program consists of a ball that falls from the top of the screen and bounces on the floor before coming to a rest. The program uses a method that is called 50 times a second (the rate at which the gametimer ticks) and in which refreshes the screen and places the ball at its current x and y positions which are affected by gravity and the s key. When the s key is pressed the ball's height is increased.
However, in the current version of my program the ball just jumps 50 pixels when the s key is pressed. How would I make it so there is a smooth transition when the s key is pressed? The high refresh rate is kind of confusing me. Here is my current code (not including the method the refreshes and the method that draws the ball):

```
public void keyPressed(keyEvent event) {
    if (event.KeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
        firstball.BallLocation();
    }
}

public void BallLocation() {
    currentPositionY = currentPositionY - 50 - currentGravity;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by smooth transition? Do you want it to look like the ball hits an invisible barrier and bounces up 50 pixels from that area? This wouldn't make a lot of sense because bouncing up 50 pixels from any arbitrary height will be completely unrealistic (it should bounce higher depending on its speed). What exactly are you trying to achieve with the s key press? By the way, you don't need `this` in front of those attributes.

Comment: the s key would give the ball more velocity allowing it to go higher without pressing the s key gravity would eventually cause it to come to a rest. And by smooth transition I mean when I press the s key to add velocity I don't want the ball to disappear and then reappear 50 pixels up

Comment: So you want it to increase the velocity of the ball in the upward direction? How are you accounting for the velocity of the ball in your current design? You should post your drawing-related methods that calculate the height/speed of the ball.